# Can I take a text file and use it as a variable to search for the location on a drive of a large amount file? (Using powershell)

Tags: powershell, file, variables, text, location

I have 1500+ files I need to identify the location of (if they exist on the drive). I was hoping I could put them in a text file and have PowerShell use the file to search for each file instead of entering each filename in the script.

I know what drive they will be on and what the files are named (if the exist). But there are millions of files that these 1500+ could be among, in vast amounts of different directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store those 1500 files in text file and read it using Get-Content into a variable and loop through it to test if file exist.

Also you can use [multi threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/santhse/invokeall) to improve the search performance.

```
$csv = Get-Content "c:\temp\temp.txt" #store your 1500 files in temp.csv

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

foreach($item in $csv){

       if($_.Name -eq $item)
       { 
         $_.FullName | Out-File 'C:\Temp\Result.txt' -Append
       }    
  }
}
```